# How do I refresh a div without adding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to refresh the div, but it's duplicating everything else.
Before I do anything, the page looks like this: [initial page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RFsn.png)
The second button is supposed to refresh the div, but when I do, this is what I get:[after trying to refresh, it refreshes it, but duplicates everything else](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3I6i.png)
How do I make it so it only refreshes the div?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <br/>
    <div id='ff'>something</div>
    <input id='input'/>
    <button id='btn1'>first</button>
    <button id='btn2'>second</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#btn1').click(function(){
               var input=$('#input').val();
               $('#ff').text(input);
           });
           $('#btn2').click(function(){
              $('#ff').load('thing2.html'); 
           });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: is the name of this file thing2.html?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the issue... [codepen](http://codepen.io/NDfool/pen/gLRvMo?editors=0010)

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
$('#ff').load('thing2.html');
```

You are only updating your div with id="ff", but you are loading into the entire contents of thing2.html.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for? If not, can you explain a bit more?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btn1').click(function(){
       var input=$('#input').val();
       $('#ff').text(input);
   });
   $('#btn2').click(function(){
      $('#input').val('');
   });
});
```

```html
<div id='ff'>something</div>
    <input id='input'/>
    <button id='btn1'>first</button>
    <button id='btn2'>second</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the things2.html again, hence its duplicating.
I have used location.reload() to refresh and its working fine. Is this you are looking for??

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#btn1').click(function(){
           var input=$('#input').val();
           $('#ff').text(input);
       });
       $('#btn2').click(function(){
         // $('#ff').load('things.html'); 
         location.reload();
       });
    });
```